# Get clicked label in jQuery Flot "plotclick" event

Tags: jquery, events, click, flot

So I have a method in jQuery for catching click events on my Flot chart:

```
$("#placeholder").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {
    alert("clicked");
});
```

I know the clicked values from item['datapoint'] array. But where can I find the label of curve I clicked?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at `item.series.label`:

```
$("#placeholder").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {
    if (item) { 
        alert(item.series.label);
    }
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KwkqK/3/).